# Mircosoft webhook URL connection throwing SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, microsoft-teams

When I'm trying to connect the webhook URL from Postman it works fine, But When I'm trying to connect from my UAT server I'm getting the below error.

I/O error on POST request for "https://xxxxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx@xxx/IncomingWebhook/3432432434":
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I know it's asking for a ca certificate but How Can I download the certificate for the webhook URL when I'm calling the URL from Chrome it's showing "This page isn’t working".

Any help will be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter an SSLHandshakeException while trying to connect to a Microsoft webhook URL, it indicates that there is an issue with the SSL handshake process during the HTTPS connection establishment. This error typically occurs due to problems with the SSL/TLS certificate, SSL configuration, or network settings.

If you want to "download the certificate" for the webhook URL, you might be referring to the SSL/TLS certificate that ensures secure communication between your browser and the server. However, in the context of webhooks, you don't usually interact with the webhook URL directly using a browser.

Export the SSL certificate of a website using Google Chrome:

1.Click the Secure button (a padlock) in an address bar

2.Click the Show certificate button

3.Go to the Details tab

4.Click the Export button

5.Specify the name of the file you want to save the SSL certificate to, keep the “Base64-encoded ASCII, single certificate” format and click the Save button